# Trying to set PHP 5.5 support using .htaccess file by adding this line AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I developed a website using Xampp 1.8.3, PHP version 5.5.3 on Windows 7. I have a hosting account to test my website.

The hosting details are:

```
Apache version      2.4.6
PHP version         5.3.27
MySQL version       5.5.32-cll
Architecture        x86_64
Operating system    Linux
```

The `password_hash()` and `verify_password()` functions belongs to PHP 5.5 and ofcourse these are not available in the old PHP versions.

To fix this issue, my hosting people asked me to add these lines in .htaccess file.

```
# Use PHP 5.5
AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php
```

Now my .htaccess file on the server looks like this.

```
# PHP 5.5
AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Is there any issue if my hosting has Linux Operating system and i developed my website on windows 7?

It still does not work after these changes being made by me. I googled a lot but could not find the solution. Please help me and suggest me what is wrong going on. If you want to check my website, here is a link [My Website Link](http://forexincome8home.com/)

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldnt it be `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php`? This works ofcourse only if your provider supports php 5.5. It would be a good idea to ask him about this.

Comment: Actually, my hosting company suggested me to use `AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php`. But i am going to try `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php` now.

Comment: No its not working. By opening my website starts downloading the `index.php` file that is available in the same directory where `.htaccess` file resides.

Comment: you didn't specify your exact problem. In the latest comment you say about downloading the index.php via the browser, I had similar problem which was resolved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129120/browser-shows-save-dialog-with-application-x-httpd-php54/24157965#24157965