# Browser forces downloading the php page when I want to open the page

Tags: php, apache, laravel, vps

I use a VPS for my website. its based on Laravel framework and I have sat up php54 for my website.

Now when I want to open the website (index.php in the public folder of Laravel),
browser just force downloading the file as a *application/x-httpd-php54* file type.

I tested adding

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

and `AddHandler` to the .htaccess in the public folder.
Neither worked!

I should mention if I enter the ip of my website or enter the name of page it opens the website with no problem.

- ip loads mysite
- www.example.com loads mysite
- example.com/index.php loads mysite

But for `example.com` browser forces downloading the file!!!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `application/x-httpd-php`... or `AddHandler php5-script .php`?

Comment: you should be putting those into the main httpd.conf, unless you have a very good reason to enable php only on a per-site basis...

Comment: @RocketHazmat: not really. you can have multiple versions of php installed, and choose which is used by putting the version number at the end.

Comment: @MarcB: Ok.  Wasn't sure :-)

Comment: @MarcB I did, no success, its strange, few resource I could found in internet about this problem

Comment: why ip works but domain doesn't!!! I use freedns.afraid.org could it be the source of problem?

Comment: @Ahmad No, your DNS provider makes no difference.  The problem is your web server configuration is broken.

Comment: @Ahmad There's PLENTY of resources for this. Apache isn't loading the PHP interpreter. It's a server-configuration problem.

Comment: @MikeB Thank you, I am just editing my old questions, I found a solution for it which I wrote it as the answer, if you found any explanation for the solution I offered you could enter your answer. Also if you found the question or the answer useful, please vote them. now I do need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the server document root is XXX and I have a virtual host named *example.com* with the same document root;

Therefor when I enter the ip, it loaded the document root and it is fine, if I enter the domain name it tries to load the page from virtual host which was unsuccessful.

I deleted the virtual host, because I didn't need virtual host when I could handle my website via the server itself.

Now everything works!